# How to throw an exception when creating a HBaseClient object (using AsynchBase)?

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

```
            try
            {
                hbaseClient = new HBaseClient(quorum_spec,base_path);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //Do Something
            }
```

I'm using the Asynchbase library. Currently I'm giving the host which runs Zookeeper and HBase Master as `quorum_spec`. I need to throw an exception when wrong host is given. When I give wrong host for `quorum_spec` HBaseClient doesn't throw any exception. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: does the code reach the cath of the exception?

Comment: @fmodos No, the control doesn't reach the catch

Comment: so debug it and try to identify what is going on